# setns from sched.h on MacOSX

Tags: c, macos

Is there something like [`setns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html) (from `<sched.h>`) on MacOSX?

Comment: This seems to be a XY problem. Please describe what you want to achieve, instead of describing the solution you imagine. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I want to port some Linux code which uses `setns` to MacOSX.

Comment: Do so by finding out what setns is used to achieve and then ask how to achieve it, please.

Comment: But even then, I still would want to know (just for curiosity), if there is sth like `setns` on MacOSX.

Comment: (Btw, what `setns` does is documented in the page I linked. That's exactly what I want to achieve.)

Comment: (Also, maybe the answer is simply, there is nothing equivalent like namespaces on OSX, so this does not exist, or whatever.)

Comment: Having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813867/3386109), I'm pretty sure that there's nothing equivalent in MacOS.